# Button visibility based on SharePoint groups and its not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I Created a list and managed those items with unique permissions.

Here are the steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Additionally, please check below codes for 2 SharePoint user groups:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the exact issue here? Are you member of Admin group or are you Site collection administrator (SCA)? If yes, you will be able to see the Admin button in app.

Comment: Issue is  i removed my access in Admin groups and users group but still its showing Admin buttons,visibility is not working as expected and i am checking access through unique permission approach so

Comment: Are you a Site collection administrator (SCA) for this site? If yes, you will be able to see the button as SCA user can read all items from all lists even when you use item level permissions. In this case, you ask your colleagues to test the application.

Comment: I tested with my colleague but though i am site collection administer it should not be visible since i am managing unique permission for list item,i dont have access also if i add one or more users in admin group its not working for all uers, i am not sure i tried using filter etc but no luck also in same security list i created2 items in security list and each item has unique permission with different sharepoint groups,admin item in the security list has unique permission to admin sharepoint group and user item is managed with unique permission and its user should be visible if theygot access

Comment: As I stated in my above comments, if you are SCA you will be able to read all items across all lists in a site (even when you have used unique permissions on list items). This is default feature of SharePoint. Only limited users who manages/administrate site should have SCA access. Check if "Admin" SharePoint group is also added under SCA section. If yes, you will need to remove it from there in order to use it in your power apps application permissions.

Comment: One more thing, use inner function in your formula like: `!IsBlank(Lookup(Security, Title = "Admin").Title)` as the `IsBlank` function tests for a blank value or an empty string.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I tried below formula and checked with different account access and still no luck. Set(HRuser,!IsBlank(LookUp(Security,Title="HR").Title)); Then i set the visible property of button to HRuser

Comment: After using formula like above should work for you. Make sure user you are testing with is not member of HRUser or not a SCA --> If these conditions are satisfied, the button will be hidden. If user is member or HRUser group or SCA --> button will be visible.

Comment: Is it working as expected now?

Comment: Yes now it worked.Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, I have added our conversation as an answer with with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula in below format to check if user is member of SharePoint group:

```
Set(varIsHRUser, !IsBlank(LookUp(Security, Title = "HR").Title));
```

Then set this inside `Visible` property of button control:

```
varIsHRUser
```

**Note**:

1. If you are a Site collection administrator (SCA) user for this site you will be able to see all the buttons as SCA user can read all items from all lists even when you use item level (unique) permissions. This is default feature in SharePoint for SCA users.
2. Make sure user you are testing with is not member of HRUser or not a SCA --> if these conditions are satisfied, the button will be hidden. If user is member of HRUser group or SCA --> button will be visible.